# How do generate random numbers, while avoiding numbers already used

Tags: python, random, numbers, generator

How do i generate random numbers but have the numbers avoid numbers already used.
I have a TXT file with thousands of sets of numbers and i need to generate a series of random numbers while avoiding these.

IE,  TXT - 0102030405
my random number needs to avoid this number.

on a side note,   how can i split up the TXT 10 digit number into 5, two digit numbers?
then how can i generate random numbers based off of that.

Comment: what do you mean by generate a random number based off a 5 digit number? Do you mean avoid those 5 digit numbers ?

Comment: on a side note,  all numbers in the txt document are CSV.  
they look like this: "0102030405" 1
                     "0202030405" 4

Comment: yes,  the TXT number as a whole, needs to be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

You could load up all previously found random numbers into a dictionary, then just check whether new_random in dictionary, and if it is try a new random number.

For the second party, say your ten digit number is stored in variable ten_digits.

```
ten_digits = '1234567890'
```

you can break this up into 5 two digit numbers by doing

```
[x + y for x, y in zip(ten_digits[::2], ten_digits[1::2]
>>> ['12', '34', '56', '78', '90']
```

Comment: yo sam, get off stack overflow. You are suppose to be at work.

Comment: Hmm,
lets say that we have [10,12,21,32,45]

if the random number generator makes:  10 12 20 20 20
would that fail the check through the dictionary because  10, and 12?

Comment: For the txt digits, i know the first one is X and the 3rd is Y
['X',??.'Y',??,??]
so my random numbers only need to be checked for the other 3 places.
i suppose i could do it separately...

Answer (score 1):

If you need to maintain the file (which I think you do, in order to add new numbers), I would suggest you to "forget" using a plain text file and use SQLite or any other embedded DB that is backed up in a file, as you probably don't want to load all the numbers in memory.

The "feature" (or better said, data structure) you want from SQLite is a B-Tree, so you can retrieve the numbers fast. I'm saying this, because you could also try to find a library that implements B-Trees, and then you wouldn't need SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the numbers as IDs?  You should probably look into using a hash table.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table

I'm not terribly familiar with Python but I'm sure there is a substring function you can give it (as arguments) an index to start the substring and the number of characters to copy.

Answer (score 0):

If you your list is relatively small you could load it into a [set](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) and check against that:

```
random_number not in number_set
```

To split the number you could use slices:

```
s='0102030405'
n=2
result = [s[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(s), n)]
```