# Loading a python dictionary with variables

Tags: python, dictionary

How do i load a text file full of 10 digit codes separated by a return into a dictionary in python?
Then how do i cross check the variables in the dictionary with my own variables?

Ok,  it is simple really.  I have a TXT file containing 1000 or so 10 digit sequences looks like this:

121001000

000000000

121212121

I need to input these files into a dictionary then be able to take a number that i receive and cross check it with this database so it does NOT match.
IE 0000000001  =/=  any previous entry.

Comment: What would be the key or the value? Why wouldn't you store it in a list instead?

Comment: please include what you have so far, so that we can better assist you.

Comment: Please clarify how the first question relates to the second?

Comment: wow really?  negative because you don't know how to read?

Comment: I would guess people votes negative because it seems like you think someone will code everything for you, since you have not written anything about what you've tried or already know.

Comment: @mike: people are likely to be downvoting for the reason given in the down button tooltip: "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful". You don't seem to have tried anything, nor are you especially clear in your question.

Comment: it's not that i'm not doing research.  I just can't make heads or tails of the tutorial provided within the python help files.
I am trying to learn how to do this.  After an example i can easily take it and try out each combination.     You don't have to code it for me, just give me an example and viola.

Comment: Which tutorial are you referring to, and what do you find unclear about it?

Comment: really?  [B] THE TUTORIAL PROVIDED WITHIN THE PYTHON HELP FILES [/B]
more specifically V.2.7.1

Comment: The question is based on this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7033542/how-do-generate-random-numbers-while-avoiding-numbers-already-used/7033588#7033588

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to store the numbers in a way that makes it easy to look up "Is this other value already there?", but you don't actually have "values" to associate with these "keys" - so you don't really want a `dict` (associative array), but rather a `set`.

Python file objects are iterable, and iterating over them gives you each line of the file in turn. Meanwhile, Python's container types (including `set`) can be constructed from iterables. So making a `set` of the lines in the file is as simple as `set(the_file_object)`. And since this is Python, checking if some other value is in the set is as simple as `some_other_value in the_set`.

Answer (score 0):

On reading text from files, try looking over the python document for [input/output](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html). Additionally look through [data structures](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.htm) tutorial.
[Dictionary](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) usually has a key and a value, that corresponds to the key:

```
name: "John"
age: 13
```

If you are just looking for the structure to read the values from the file, [list](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange) seems to be more appropriate, since you did not specify anything about the designation of those values.

Comment: Could i break the numerical sequence into 5 separate 2 digit parts and associate them with a set of keys?
IE 0102030405
Broken into: 
01 02 03 04 05   with the keys as such:
A  B  C  D  E

Could i use the same keys for a different value?
IE: 01 02 03 04 05
    06 07 08 09 10
     A  B  C  D  E
 So A returns 01, 06

Comment: The keys in the dictionary should be unique, so you can't have multiple entries with key "A". I am not really sure what you are trying to achieve with this.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the file's contents as numbers and not as strings:

```
file_data = set()
for line in open('/some/file/with/sequences.txt'):
    file_data.add(int(line))
```

then later:

```
if some_num not in file_data:
    do_something_with(some_num)
```

If you have blank lines or garbage in the file, you'll want to add some error checking.